# Copy From Azure blob to GCP bucket - Through Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I would need your guidance on my terraform code error below.

My use case is need to create "**Transfer Service | cloud**" job in **GCP Data Transfer** through Terraform. That should copy from **Azure storage** To **GCP storage bucket**.

Here is my Terraform code, but it throws error in "terraform apply". I don't find any sample code for Azure blob to GCP storage.

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      # version = "~> 2.65"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "google" {
  project = "gce-os-hardened-images"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-a"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "blob-backup-bucket"   {
  name                        = "mybucket-new"
  storage_class               = "NEARLINE"
  project                     = "myproject"
  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}

resource "google_storage_transfer_job" "azure-to-gcp-new" {
  description = "Storage Migrate from Az to GCP"
  project     = "myproject"

  transfer_spec {
    object_conditions {
      max_time_elapsed_since_last_modification = "600s"
    }

    transfer_options {
      delete_objects_unique_in_sink = false
    }


    azure_blob_storage_data_source {
      storage_account = "myazurestorage"
      container       = "testcontainer"
      path = ""

      azure_credentials {
        sas_token = "******************"
      }
    }

    gcs_data_sink {
      bucket_name = google_storage_bucket.blob-backup-bucket.name
    }
  }

  schedule  {
    schedule_start_date {
      year  = 2021
      month = 7
      day   = 12
    }
    schedule_end_date {
      year  = 2021
      month = 7
      day   = 12
    }
    start_time_of_day {
      hours   = 13
      minutes = 30
      seconds = 0
      nanos   = 0
    }
  }
}
```

It throws the below error.

```
Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []interface {}
2021-07-12T19:46:27.990+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.74.0_x5.exe:
2021-07-12T19:46:27.990+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.74.0_x5.exe: goroutine 117 [running]:
2021-07-12T19:46:27.990+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.74.0_x5.exe: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/google.expandAzureBlobStorageData(...)
....
....
....
2021/07/12 19:46:28 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: unlocked by closing terraform.tfstate
2021-07-12T19:46:28.045+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.74.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-google_v3.74.0_x5.exe pid=13196 error="exit status 2"
2021-07-12T19:46:28.045+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited




!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! TERRAFORM CRASH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Terraform crashed! This is always indicative of a bug within Terraform.
A crash log has been placed at "crash.log" relative to your current
working directory. It would be immensely helpful if you could please
report the crash with Terraform[1] so that we can fix this.

information is available on the first line of crash.log. You can also
get it by running 'terraform --version' on the command line.

SECURITY WARNING: the "crash.log" file that was created may contain
sensitive information that must be redacted before it is safe to share
on the issue tracker.

[1]: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! TERRAFORM CRASH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an error in Google terraform provider but has been fixed now. Using newer versions of provider should fix this issue.

Checkout following github issues for more info :

- [Azure blob storage transfer terraform panic crash #9547](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/9547)
- [Azure blob storage transfer crash #9650](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/9650)